# What gets updated in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and I am a little confused about what gets updated every time the state or props change. For instance:

```
const Foo = props => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(null)

  let a
  useEffect(() => {
    a = 'Some fetched data'
  }, [])
}
```

Now if the state (i.e. `someState`) or props get updated, does it run through the function again, making `a` undefined? Does only JSX elements that depend on the state/props and the hooks that use them get affected? What changes exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand how the `state` affect your component, you could check [this example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-unmujq?file=index.js). It shows you how the local variable of your component act when a state changes. This behavior is exactly the same when the component receive a new prop. Here is the code just in case :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState('default');
  
  // see how the displayed value in the viewchanges after the setTimeout
  let a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000); 

  React.useEffect(() => {
    a = "new a"; // Does nothing in the view
    setTimeout(() => setState("hello state"), 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {a} - {state}
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

What you can see is :

- `a` is initialized with a random value and it is displayed in the view
- `useEffect` is triggered. `a` is edited but does not re-render your component
- After 2 seconds, `setState` is called, updating the state `state`
- At this point, `a` value has changed for a new one because your component is re-rendered after a state update. `state` also changed for what you gave to it

So for your question :

> if the state (i.e. someState) or props get updated, does it run through the function again, making a undefined? Does only JSX elements that depend on the state/props and the hooks that use them get affected? What changes exactly?

The answer is yes, it does run through the function again, and the state/props that has been updated are updated in the JSX. Local variable like `a` will be set to their default value.